# ¿Cómo mandar a un arreglo los números no repetidos de otro arreglo c++?

Tags: array

buenas quisiera que me ayudaran es esto... estoy trabajando con ensamblador para x86 y tengo una duda...

Necesito hacer que un arreglo que tenga números tanto repetidos como no repetidos, leerlo y sacar de dicho arreglo los números no repetidos y mandarlo a otro arreglo... y no sé cómo realizarlo es lo unico que me falta de verdad necesitó ayuda gracias de antemano...

Comment: No se entiende bien tu pregunta: ¿ que es lo que no sabes ? leer el arreglo en c++, crear uno nuevo, buscar los datos repetidos, copiarlos ... Si colocaras lo que llevas hecho, sería mas fácil ayudarte. Tal vez deberías leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: PRIMERO NECESITO SACAR DE UN ARREGLO LOS NUMEROS PRIMOS Y GUARDARLOS EN OTRO ARREGLO PERO EN ASSEMBLER X86